# How to reach GoDaddy live chat support

Tags: godaddy

Where can I access GoDaddy live chat support? I could only reach the phone support which is not available in my country and email support is no longer an option.

Where can I find the live chat support?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's blatantly off-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure I find it off-topic, if it is about using GoDaddy's web admin interface, which would be a web application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GoDaddy live chat support is only visible through a U.S.-based IP address. To have a chat with GoDaddy support, use a proxy and a chat dialog will pop up soon enough wherever you go on the site.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can go here.

https://gethuman.com/chat/GoDaddy-com

and if you want phone support

https://www.godaddy.com/contact-us.aspx